# android block map generation through text file

Tags: android, collision

(Just to be clear I'm asking for guideance not for someone to program this whole thing(unless they want to XD))

Hi, I'm currently trying to make a game for android in which you can build a map out of blocks(there are several types but we'll just use walls here).

The map is going to be 100x20 blocks, in which the players can put any of the blocks available inside in any order, and it's going to be stored as a text file "Let's call it "mapFile""(this part I've already solved) in which 0's would be nothing and 1's would be walls.

Now, the problem is that when you start playing the map, the game will have to load all the blocks to make the obstacles, but I want it to do it in a specific way (mainly to make the game go smoother and doesn't have to check 2000 blocks every update):

-make groups of blocks(lines, squares, rectangles) as 1 obstacle so there os only 1 collision detection in a large amount of blocks(the difficult part is to divide a complex shape in the best way)

-divide the map into 5x5 chunks so it doesn't have to check every obstacle in order to see if it should be drawn(it would just draw the chunk in which the player is in and the ones surrounding it)

The output from this should be a 4 levels array(or something similar):
Array[Ychunk][Xchunk][obstacle][x,y,xBlocks,yBlocks,type]
(Type is just the num of the block in the map(in this case it's 1 because it's the number for wall in my app)

For now the game has:

-An array with all the obstacles info (x,y,xBlocks,yBlocks,type)

-Only updates obstacles if they are a small distance from the player(still has to check them all)

-Only draws obstacles that are inside the window(also has to check them all)

Comment: 2D tile game? [Tile Based Games](http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/links.html).

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, You don't need an array with all the map info, what you need is a 2D array of tiles. The tile object will contain all the info like the image, isSolid, etc.
- Secondly, You will always have the player visible, so that acts as your anchor, **Only** show the tiles around your player and render that to the screen. Its makes no sense to render the tiles that will not be rendered on the screen e.g., If the player is at the center and the screen renders 5x5 tiles then +/- 2 tiles of the player tile. Same goes for checking if the tile is visible **No, need to check all**
- Lastly, Again you don't need to check the player collision with all the obstacles, only need to check  collision with the tile that the player is going to move on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as is said in the "For now the game has" part, there is an array for the obstacles only that has their info, and the game only updates and renders objects inside the window, the part saying that it has to check them all is so that it knows if they are inside or not.

Comment: What is xblock, yblock and xchunk, ychunk? The type, I am assuming it to be tile-type.

Comment: xblock and yblock are the number of blocks in each direction that the obstacle is made of, xchunk and ychunk are the chunks in the map(a chunk is a 5x5 spaces area)